# Iterate through dict hierarchy in json with python loop

Tags: python, json

Okay I did some reading and should now rephrase my question:

I have restructured my josn to a tree like dict:

```
[{
  "id": "Bosniak",
  "system": 
          {
          "0": "Wurde ein Nieren Protokoll gemacht, ist <25% der Lesion KM aufnehmend, und ist kein Fettgewebe zu sehen\n(1) alles trifft zu?\n(2) trifft nicht zu",
          "1": {"0": "KM-aufnehmende Lesion >3cm, heterogene Lesion, viel Verkalkung?\n(1) mind. eins davon trifft zu\n(2) trifft nicht zu",
                "1":"Bosniak1", "2":"Bosniak II"},
          "2": {"0": "Was ist zu sehen?\n(1) >25% KM-aufnehmend oder fettig\n(2) homogene Lesion 20 - 30 HU", 
                "1": "Bosniak IV", "2":"Bosnaik V"}
          }         

}]
```

In a prior step I call an id in my dict, like "Bosniak" in this example. Now I want to iterate through the "system" key, Q&A-like via inputs through my console, until I have reached the end of a list (i.e. "Bosniak II")

I have this loop:

```
i = "1" #that is the index for the item with id "Bosniak" in my dict
while True:
    qloop = input("Select an option: ", )
    #probably here I need a recursive function 
    #or whatever where I can dynamically change my path,
    # so that I can call items in my json dict until the 
    #end of a nested layer is reached
    if #here I have some other code, not important
    else:
        print(data[i]["system"][qloop]["0"]) 
        #if I type "1" it prints "KM-aufnehmende Lesion >3cm, heterogene Lesion, viel Verkalkung?\n(1) mind. eins davon trifft zu\n(2) trifft nicht zu"
    break
```

The expected output is being asked by my console "Select an option: ", iterating through my tree like dict based on my inputs, until there is no sublayer left, where it would finally print i.e. "Bosniak II"

Comment: At least for me it's unclear which output you expect. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: You're breaking out of the loop in both `if` and `else:`. So the loop never repeats, it's not an infinite loop.

Comment: Why are some of the keys in the `Choice X` dictionaries integers and others are strings?

Comment: There's no need to put `continue` at the end of a loop. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them.

Comment: BTW, `[f"{qloop}"]` is a complicated way to write `[qLoop]`.

Comment: If you want to loop over the values in a dictionary, use `for value in d.values():`. `print(data[i]["system"][f"{qloop}"][f"{l}"])` won't work when `l == 2` because that key is not a string.

Comment: And if there are multiple dictionary entries in the outer list you need to loop over all of those entries (e.g. `for entry in data`).

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run the program, it is throwing me an error `NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?` instead of an infinite loop. And after fixing the above error, getting the error `KeyError: '2'`, which is because of the key `2` inside `Choice 1` and `Choice 2` of `system`. Made some tweaks to the existing code so that it will run successfully but it would be great if the exact goal or use case is provided. Note: As per the tweaks, Updated key `2` to `'2'` data variable dict and added var `i` so that it can be incremented.

```
data = [
   {
     "final result":{
     "choice 1+3":"result1",
     "choice 1+4":"result2",
     "choice n":"result n"
  },
  "id":"lorem",
  "system":{
     "0":{
        "0":"initial question",
        "1":"Choice 1",
        "2":"Choice 2"
     },
     "Choice 1":{
            "2":"Choice 4",
            "0":" second question",
            "1":"Choice 3"
         },
         "Choice 2":{
            "2":"Choice 6",
            "0":" second question",
            "1":"Choice 5"
         }
      }
   }
]                        
i = 0                        
while True:
    qloop = input("Select an option: ", )
    if qloop == "R":
        break
    else:
        for l in range(len(data[i]["system"][f"{qloop}"])):
            print(data[i]["system"][f"{qloop}"][f"{l}"])
        break
    i += 1
    continue
```

if you give the input as `choice 1+3`, it would fail because we're not fetching values of only `system` from the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet using a function:

```py
data = [{
  "id": "Bosniak",
  "system": 
          {
          "0": "Wurde ein Nieren Protokoll gemacht, ist <25% der Lesion KM aufnehmend, und ist kein Fettgewebe zu sehen\n(1) alles trifft zu?\n(2) trifft nicht zu",
          "1": {"0": "KM-aufnehmende Lesion >3cm, heterogene Lesion, viel Verkalkung?\n(1) mind. eins davon trifft zu\n(2) trifft nicht zu",
                "1":"Bosniak1", "2":"Bosniak II"},
          "2": {"0": "Was ist zu sehen?\n(1) >25% KM-aufnehmend oder fettig\n(2) homogene Lesion 20 - 30 HU", 
                "1": "Bosniak IV", "2":"Bosnaik V"}
          }         

}]

def get_dict_data(json_data):
    if isinstance(json_data, dict):
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            print(f": {value}") if key != "0" else print(value)
        choice = input("Select an option: ")
        if choice in json_data:
          get_dict_data(json_data[choice])
    else:
        print(json_data)

indx = "1"
get_dict_data(data[0]["system"][indx])
```

---

```
KM-aufnehmende Lesion >3cm, heterogene Lesion, viel Verkalkung?
(1) mind. eins davon trifft zu
(2) trifft nicht zu
: Bosniak1
: Bosniak II
Select an option: 
2
Bosniak II
```

If you want to iterate the entire data you can then use a while loop:
**Replace** the last two lines of code in the above snippet with:

```
indx = 0
while indx < len(data[0]["system"]):
    get_dict_data(data[0]["system"][str(indx)])
    print("")
    indx +=1
```

---

```
Wurde ein Nieren Protokoll gemacht, ist <25% der Lesion KM aufnehmend, und ist kein Fettgewebe zu sehen
(1) alles trifft zu?
(2) trifft nicht zu

KM-aufnehmende Lesion >3cm, heterogene Lesion, viel Verkalkung?
(1) mind. eins davon trifft zu
(2) trifft nicht zu
: Bosniak1
: Bosniak II
Select an option: 
2
Bosniak II

Was ist zu sehen?
(1) >25% KM-aufnehmend oder fettig
(2) homogene Lesion 20 - 30 HU
: Bosniak IV
: Bosnaik V
Select an option: 
1
Bosniak IV
```