# Iterate through nested layers of a dictionary via user input python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

posted a similar question before, however, the conditions changes a bit so that I want to rephrase it.

I have the following dict structure:

```
[{
        "id": "id01",
        "system": 
                    {
                    "0": "initial question \n Choice A \n Choice B",
                    "1": {"0": "Answer Choice A\n Second Choice C \n Second Choice D",
                          "1":"Final Answer Choice AC", 
                          "2":"Final Answer Choice AD"},
                    "2": {"0": "Answer Choice B\n Second Choice A \n Second Choice B", 
                          "1": "Final Answer Choice BA", 
                          "2":"Final Answer Choice BB"}
                    }         
    
}]
```

It is a tree like dictonary, where the user can iterate through via console inputs.
Thats my code:

```
while True:
            qloop = input("Select an option: ", )

            if qloop == "R":
                break
            else:
                print(data[i]["system"][qloop]) #here I want to use the qloop input to stepwise iterate through the nested layers of my tree-like dict.
            break
        if qloop == "R":
            continue
        else:
            break
```

So, I over my console the user is asked to make a choice for an item (in this example "id01"). Lets say the user types "1" after the inital question the code should print Answer Choice A and then again the user can choose until the end of one path in this decision tree like dict is reached.

Any ideas how I can achieve that, resp. it would be a great bonus if you could also undo your choices stepwise with lets say the "R" key.

Comment: In your example, it looks like sometimes you have a list of dictionaries with an `id` key, and sometimes you have a dictionary with numbered options.  Are there other ways the nested dictionaries might be formatted?  It's not easy to write code that can handle completely arbitrary structures in a way that's user-friendly, but if you come up with a regular format and use it consistently it's easy.

Comment: Not a code writing service, but I'll answer in general terms since it's a general question. Simple recursion is your answer. Write a function that takes a dict. Present the keys as choices, then returns the key-value as the result. If the value is a dict, call the function again with that dict.

Comment: Your `0` entry should be: `"0": {"0":"initial question \n Choice A \n Choice B"}`. You are changing your structure based on the amount of possibilities, and it is going to give you nothing but headaches.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I think `"0"` is always supposed to be keyed a question, so it's fine. Would be better to explicitly have a `{'prompt':str, 'choices':[choice_1_dict, choice_2_dict,...]}` structure though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through dict hierarchy in json with python loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817241/iterate-through-dict-hierarchy-in-json-with-python-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Your desired chain of events isn't very clear from your code, but I suppose you could use something like this function

```py
def traverse_choices(q_ch:dict): 
    while isinstance(q_ch, dict):
        print(q_ch['0'])
        if (user_resp:=input("Select an option: ")) not in ['R', *q_ch]:
            print('Invalid selection. Please enter a valid option [or "R" to exit].')
            continue
        if user_resp=='R': return 'R'
        if user_resp!='0': q_ch = q_ch[user_resp]
    print(q_ch)
```

and maybe utilize it as below

```py
            qloop = traverse_choices(data[i]["system"]) ## will return "R" or None
        if qloop != "R": break
        continue ## ONLY IF THERE IS ANYTHING AFTER IT [IN THE OUTER LOOP] TO SKIP
    #### REST OF OUTER LOOP ####
```

[I'm assuming that the *`if qloop == "R": continue` `else: break`* part in your code snippet is nested inside a conditional block inside another loop, because there is no point in having anything in a loop after an unconditional `break` or `continue`...]

[image: op]

---

About

> ```py
>         if qloop == "R":
>             continue
>         else:
>             break
> ```

**Note that you don't need to use `else` after `if...break` or `if...continue`;** and if there's nothing in the loop after `break`, you can just use <kbd>**`if qloop != "R": break`**</kbd>.